# Finance paper with different decimal places

Tags: writing-style, economics

I am writing a finance paper and I change my data frequency from monthly to daily data,

With monthly data, two decimal places is fine. However, my daily results look strange with two decimal places.
For example, *1.0042* becomes to *1.00;* then I have a tables full with *1.00,* which is not informative for my readers.

Can I increase the number of decimal places for the daily results?

Any examples of this would be appreciated!

Comment: Can any of the close voters state why they consider this off-topic? I fail to see any reason for this.

Comment: If all of your data is of the form 1+small number, why not cut the 1 and use percentages? A change of 0.42% is easier to read than a factor of 1.0042.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue of *significant figures*. You say the value of 1.00 is not informative, but trailing zeros after a decimal point do, in fact, carry meaning. Showing a number that's been rounded to 1.00 indicates that the true value is somewhere between 0.995 and 1.004 - we know that the hundredths place rounds to 0. If you show the number as just 1, I can only infer that the true value is somewhere between 0.5 and 1.4. You're losing information, since we know that the tenths place is indeed zero, and that the hundredths place rounds to zero. Keeping the trailing zeros after the decimal point shows the level of precision with which you have measured your values.

You are free to round the numbers to whatever precision is meaningful for your domain, but keep in mind that your representation can reflect the precision of the underlying data - there is indeed a difference between a value of 1 and a value of 1.00.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question "Can I increase the number of decimal places for the daily results?"

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing a finance paper ... Can I increase the number of decimal places for the daily results?

If it's done in other papers in your field, then yes. If it's *never* done, then ask a more senior colleague, or an editor / program committee member of the publication you're targeting.

Whatever you decide to do, make your choice explicit and clear; that way nobody will be misled.